# Redirect issues w/ non-www requests to www - root domain without path not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect all requests to the root (without `www.`) of a domain that I am managing to the `www.` address (e.g.: `example.com` -> `www.example.com`). I have modified my `.htaccess` file and I have managed to get requests to the root domain *with* a path to the `www.` domain (e.g.: `example.com/somepath/` properly directs to `www.example.com/somepath/`). However, requests to the root domain *without* a path or trailing slash are not redirecting properly (e.g.: `example.com` !-> `www.example.com`). So, it seems like I have things working correctly when there is a trailing slash, but not when there is not (e.g.: for the root domain). I have included the contents of my `.htaccess` file below. Thanks in advance!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect paths of non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This cannot be the full set of rules you have implemented. There is no trace of a rule that redirects requests to the www host's "root" as you claim.

Comment: Right, the rule is not working fully. It will redirect example.com/products/ to www.example.com/products/, but typing example.com/products (no trailing slash) doesn't redirect to the www site. I'm trying to get all requests to the root to redirect to www.

Comment: If you think that this rule doesn't do what I am wanting it to, it's possible that it isn't and that the www site just picks up the trailing slash while the root site picks up otherwise. So, how would you fix the set of rules then to accomplish the redirection?